# Passing a class instance into another class

Tags: java, class, object, pointers, reference

I've looked everywhere but I can't seem to find an answer to this.

If I have one class (say, a Resource class) and another class (say a Sprite class) and each time I create a sprite, I pass in a reference to my Resource class (because it's required for some function) - am I correct in assuming, that all this does is creates a reference to this instance of said class?

So - if my Sprite constructor is this:

```
public Sprite(Resource res){

res.doSomething........

}
```

And I create 100 sprites, then this isn't going to cause problems because it's just passing in a reference or 'pointer'? (as opposed to creating a new instance each time).

Simple enough question I know, but I want to make sure I understand what's happening here and I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere.

Comment: This is fairly easy to test. Just modify the member data variables of the passed in object and see if the modifications remain.

Comment: All your assumptions are correct, yes.

Comment: If you use the same `Resource` for every time you instantiate a new `Sprite`, you will have 1 `Resource` object that's used in every sprite.

Comment: Thanks very much all - @PaulRenton - that is a good point regarding altering a variable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you create a new `Sprite` and pass it an existing `Resource`, the new Sprite will just have a reference to your original object.

So 100 Sprites would have 100 references to your 1 Resource.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to create eachtime a `new` instance of the class to call `doSomething()` of that particular `instance.`